# Autodesk Forge accessing b360 hub to get projects - error 404

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

I'm trying to pubhlish a project using this guide - https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/publish-model/

I am able to get the docs hub ID for the expected hub (using 3 legged token, after having Autodesk provision the b360 docs account, and setting up integration w/ forge app), and pass this into the call to get the projects (using same token, or new token) using this guide - https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/

I get back a response 404 error using the hub ID provided in the GET hubs call that starts with b.xxx from the GET hubs

```
{
"developerMessage": "The requested resource does not exist.",
"moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
"errorCode": ""
}
```

I've tried this with a. as well, instead of b. and also no prefix on hub ID with no luck. I verified that this Id matches what is shown in the account admin settings online as well.

The get request looks like this, and includes authorization token in format Bearer {{token}} where {{token}} is the (same) variable for the token that works when getting hub ID's.

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/b.e3a26052-6b48-4a03-9115-xxxxxxxxxxx/projects
```

Is my format incorrect, or is there something else going on?

Answer (score 0):

The request looks ok, incl. the hub ID (the `b.` prefix must be there). One thing to check for is whether the actual user you're using to obtain the 3-legged token has access to any projects inside this hub.

Also, what happens when you try the [GET hubs/:hub_id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-GET/) endpoint? Can you see the hub information or do you get 404 as well?

Comment: I do indeed have projects listed in this hub. When I try the GET hubs/:hub id with the same ID as above I receive a 403 error.

{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "id": "941d6027-cfcc-493e-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "status": "403",
            "code": "BIM360DM_ERROR",
            "detail": "Failed to get the hub for id b.e3a26052-6b48-4a03-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: According to the docs, the 403 error code indicates that: `The request was successfully validated but permission is not granted or the application has not been white-listed. Do not try again unless you solve permissions first.`. So it really looks like a permission issue, either with the Forge app itself, or with the user account you are trying to use to access the hub and its projects.